# Automatically create new Documents from nested objects with typegoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

What I would like to know is if there is a way that when I save a new document with many nested objects marked as `Ref` in the Typegoose class, it would automatically create new documents from these nested objects in the right collection.

For the moment, this code gives me an error :

`nestedProp: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ Prop1: 'test1', Prop2: 'test2' }" at path "nestedProp"`

```
import { getModelForClass, prop, Ref } from "@typegoose/typegoose";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export class NestedClass {
  @prop()
  Prop1!: string;
  @prop()
  Prop2?: string;
}

export class MainClass {
  @prop()
  name!: string;
  @prop({ ref: "NestedClass" })
  nestedProp?: Ref<NestedClass>;
}

let exampleObject = {
  name: "test",
  nestedProp: {
    Prop1: "test1",
    Prop2: "test2",
  },
};

async function test() {
  await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/database");
  const ClassModel = getModelForClass(MainClass);
  try {
    const u = await ClassModel.create(exampleObject);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
test();
```

I know mongoose is asking the object to come with ObjectId and not objects.

However, the problem is that I have many big classes with many nested classes and I am trying to avoid looping through all big objects to save the nested object first before the big one.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is currently not possible, but there is an issue at [Automattic/mongoose](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8115) about it